# Navigation toggle not working on 768px width Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap i want to toggle navigation on 768px screen width but its not working

see image    [image]

but its works fine with 767px screen width

see image     [image]

can you pls help to solve this issues i have tried a lot on google but cant find the solution for this.

Answer (score -1):

May be u din't added css properly, bootstrap is fully responsive it will take perfectly. while u writing css , just write for custom class only dont include bootstrap class.

Comment: everything i have check is fine and added properly issue is only with 1px difference looks fine on 767 but not on 768